# No difference in size of my apk with cruncherEnabled option disbled

Tags: android, zopfli

I'm trying to reduce the size of my apk.

So first I've compressed my pngs with `zopfli` then added

```
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled=false
}
```

in my `build.gradle` (app) and built.

But the result is same with and without that option `(gradle version 2.2.3)`

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Comment: I did what's stated in "Crunch PNG Files" section